# Nginx: Basic auth protecting folders and PHP files, but not images

Tags: authentication, nginx

I have the following Nginx config

```
location ^~ /members {
    auth_basic "Members Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/*user*/public/*site*/www/members/.htpasswd;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include     /data/config/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Set header expirations for static content
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff|mp4|flv)$ {
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
        expires         365d;
    }            
}
```

with the intention to password the /members/ directory, and all content within (.php, .jpg, .mp4 etc).

In it's current state, it prompts the user with the user/pass box as intended for .php files, however it doesn't fire the auth for the jpg images.

For clarity, the following behaviour is occuring:

- http://**site**/members - user prompted for user/pass
- http://**site**/members/category.php - user prompted for user/pass
- http://**site**/members/content/upload/example.jpg - user able to see content without login

The /members/content folder is a symlink to a folder outside of the document root folder, which I wondered whether this was a potential cause.

I have tried a host of different configs, such as removing the ^~ on the /members block, but just can't get a working config to cover all files within the directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you cleared browser cache before testing the images? With expiration like this there won't be a request to the server If the browser already had the image.

Comment: hi, I clear my cache each time, as well as requesting a new jpg each time I re-run the test but I'm seeing the same behaviour. Thanks

Comment: @Ashley_Evans This configuration should work without problems. There's something else in your server or http block that circumvents the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to define a new block to capture the images inside the members directory

```
location ~ ^/members.*\.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff|mp4|flv)$ {
   auth_basic "Members Area";
   auth_basic_user_file /home/*user*/public/*site*/www/members/.htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your input

i tried this but unfortunately it still didn't prompt me for the username/password as expected in a new Incognito window loading a new jpg file.

I tried that block both outside the main location ~/members folder, and also inside as: location ~ \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff|mp4|flv)$ but with no luck